# Laravel 10 API authentication

Tags: authentication, laravel-10

I have a question regarding what the best user authentication method would be, to use these days, and how to combine that with user/password authentication.

I have a web application with an API and I want to build one native android app (first-party) that is going to consume the API. But i want a user to authenticate within the app on the API. As of OAuth 2.1 (implicit) password grants are removed and laravel advises against using those methods. I am lingering to use the `Authorization Code Grant with PKCE` but I do not see how i can combine this with a username/password authentication.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?